# Redirect all stdout to file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe

Quite simple really. I would like something like the following example:

```
echo "Hello world. " > some/file.txt
echo "This is " > some/file.txt
echo "some awesome " > some/file.txt
echo "text!!!" > some/file.txt
```

to

```
stdOutFile = "some/file.txt"
echo "Hello world. "
echo "This is "
echo "some awesome "
echo "text!!!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this format:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "stdOutFile=some\file.txt"
(   Echo Hello world. 
    Echo This is 
    Echo some awesome 
    Echo text!!!
)>"%stdOutFile%"
```

If you're intending it to all be in the same line then perhaps:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "stdOutFile=some\file.txt"
(   For %%A In (
        "Hello world. "
        "This is "
        "some awesome "
        "text!!!"
    ) Do Set/P =%%~A<Nul
)>"%stdOutFile%"
```

**[Edit]**

You could even use the following idea:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "stdOutFile=somefile.txt"
Set "str=Hello world."
Set "str=%str% This is"
Set "str=%str% some awesome"
Set "str=%str% text!!!"
(Echo %str%)>"%stdOutFile%"
```

If your batch file isn't particularly interactive then you could just run your batch file as suggested in the other answers:

***mybatchfile.cmd***

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo Hello world. 
Echo This is 
Echo some awesome 
Echo text!!!
```

StdOut:

```bat
"mybatchfile.cmd">"some\file.txt"
```

You could also direct any errors to the same file too.

StdOut & StdErr:

```bat
"mybatchfile.cmd">"some\file.txt" 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot put the echo code into a separate `.bat` script, one way to make it a bit more "palatable", is to put the redirection with the `echo` command.

```
SET "stdOutFile=some/file.txt"
IF EXIST "%stdOutFile%" (DEL "%stdOutFile%")

echo>>"%stdOutFile%" "Hello world. "
echo>>"%stdOutFile%" "This is "
echo>>"%stdOutFile%" "some awesome "
echo>>"%stdOutFile%" "text!!!"
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the same as the OP did, you are just replacing the output file name in each row with the variable name you created. See @compo answer which is more what the OP wanted.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - I did not say this was utopia. I said it was a bit more palatable. Downvote not merited.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard OP used `>` only, which probably was the original problem. `echo >>...` is a correct and valid answer.

Comment: @Stephan yes, the answer will work, but I think more it was a case of the user does not want to rewrite the output file over again in a 100 line script where you could instead run each command and pipe to a file at the end. This answer is the same solution, besides the single `>`. It requires you to re-write the variable 100 times instead of output file 100 times. I did not downvote this though.

Comment: PS!! I am not trying to argue with anyone, I am explaining how I see the OP question compared to the answers.

Comment: didn't say, it was the best answer - just valid. Besides that, I totally agree with you.

Comment: I agree with both of you. I am glad to see Compo's answer selected. It would be boring and a violation of the DRY principle to do this. But, it would be more visually understandable and more easily edited than the OP question source.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a `.bat`-file:

```
@echo off
echo "Hello world. "
echo "This is "
echo "some awesome "
echo "text!!!"
```

Then run it like following:

```
my.bat > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an

```
@echo off
```

in the beginning of the batch file and then do

```
.\batchfile >outputfilename
```